# Adding multiple search variables to construct

Tags: php, construct

I'm writing a search engine and at the moment it searches for only the keywords that are submitted with a heap of other information. How can I ask it to look in other areas?

This is what I have:

```
$construct .= "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

This is the coded theory of what I need to do:

```
$construct .= "keywords, name, description, id LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

What is the formal way to add extra values to include?

Comment: you can do this by **AND** , where you got stuck ?

Comment: Ok so can I just write it in string and it will be read fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
$construct .= "keywords LIKE '%$search_each%' OR name LIKE '%$search_each%' OR description LIKE '%$search_each%' OR id LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

Comment: Well, It doesn't seem to work as it doesn't find entries in any of the fields with the names in the code. I'll maybe have to look at something else. The code returns fine and nothing breaks, perhaps I should look deeper

Comment: It will be more useful if you add the full query, and may be what's on the db